# SignalR IHubContext and thread safety

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

In the code sample below I've implemented a SignalR Hub that is supposed to implement the following functionality:

- Clients may listen to changes of Foo instances by invoking the Hub's *Subscribe* method with a bunch of ids that is treated as group names interally
- Unsubscribing works analog by invoking Unsubscribe
- The service layer of the web application may notify connected clients subcribed to the appropriate ids (groups) that a change has occured by invoking *OnFooChanged*

Is it safe to use a singleton for the hub context or do I need to fetch it every time inside the *OnFooChanged*? Feedback on the implementation of the other methods is welcome as well. I'm new to SignalR after all.

```
[Export]
public class FooHub : Hub
{
  private static readonly Lazy<IHubContext> ctx = new Lazy<IHubContext>(
    () => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<FooHub>());

  #region Client Methods 

  public void Subscribe(int[] fooIds)
  {
    foreach(var fooId in fooIds)
      this.Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, fooId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
  }

  public void Unsubscribe(int[] fooIds)
  {
    foreach (var fooId in fooIds)
      this.Groups.Remove(this.Context.ConnectionId, fooId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
  }

  #endregion // Client Methods

  #region Server Methods

  /// <summary>
  /// Called from service layer when an instance of foo has changed
  /// </summary>
  public static void OnFooChanged(int id)
  {
    ctx.Value.Clients.Group(id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).onFooChanged();
  }

  #endregion // Server Methods
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from the [server broadcast tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20):

> There are two reasons why you want to get the context just once:
>   getting the context is an expensive operation, and getting it once
>   ensures that the intended order of messages sent to clients is
>   preserved.

So, in other words: using the Lazy singleton is safe and the recommended way to do this. If you'd get a new context each time you want to send to a client, you'd risk messages being sent in a different order than you expect.

I'm not aware of any reason why you might want to get a new context regularly.